# VSC API for split in group action

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there VSCode api for `split in group action` as seen below?

[image: menu showing split in group command]

Somthing like

```js
const doc = await workspace.openTextDocument({
    language: "text",
  });
const editor = await window.showTextDocument(doc);
editor.edit((edit) => edit.insert(new Position(0, 0), "hello"));
editor.split() // <--- this
```

Comment: find out which command is bound to the keybinding and then execute that command with the extension API

Comment: I was thinking about the same "cheat" but I need to make sure there is no API available for it before I hack it around. But thanks

Comment: It isn't a hack.   There are many built-in commands for which an api will probably never be exposed.  The vscode team expects you to use the `executeCommand()`  for these.

Comment: I didn't know that :D Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out which command is bound to the keybinding and then execute that command with the extension API, method is (as Mark points out) `executeCommand()`